# Create an ASP.NET user control allowing customizable inner content

Tags: asp.net

I would like to know how to create an ASP.NET user control that allows for inner content (and how to render the inner content.

As a very simple example, let's say we're creating a control to create a div, so the control would be used as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="custom" TagName="MyDiv" 
    Src="~\Controls\MyDiv.ascx" %>
<html>
<head />
<body>
    <custom:MyDiv id="Div1" runat="server">
    ... customizable content here ...
    </custom:MyDiv>
</body>
<html>
```

The control should be agnostic to its inner content - i.e. any asp.net content can be added and will be rendered as per usual, and then surrounded with `<div>` and `</div>` tags.

(Note: I'm obviously not trying to make a control to simulate div tags, it's just a simple example.)

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question.  Before I suggest an answer, I think you should look into Master Pages: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages

If that doesn't provide your solution, and you want to stick with the User Control route, it won't work the way you want to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What I'm looking at doing is creating a repeating element (in my case a customized box with rounded corners, more or less.)  Looks like this is beyond what an user control can handle, so I'm investigating using a custom web server control instead.

Comment: What do you want to display inside that repeating element?  Data?  If so, I'd look into a `Repeater`.  If it truly is going to be unique to each instance of the control, a custom web server control is most likely the only option.

Comment: Sorry, I probably needed to supply more context. It's essentially a visual element that I needed to use a bunch of divs for, due to browser compatibility restraints. I have a feeling that it might change at some point (because everything changes) so I don't want to cut and paste all over the place.  It is being used repeatedly, but not in an orderly way that would work well with a repater.  So seems to need a custom web server control.  Thanks again for your assistance.